# Knockout JS grid, proihibited chars in bind statement

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I'm printing out rows of a grid with Knockout js. I'd like my view to apply a CSS class based on wether or not the index of the iteration is divisible by 2.

This is my binding statement, called for each row:

```
<data-bind="css: { $index % 2 === 0 ? 'grid_row' : 'grid_a_row' }">
```

Two problems arises:

- The use of `%` seems to be prohibited inside of an attribute
  declaration. My IDE (VS2012) doesn't recognize anything which comes
  after `%` as part of the string (I can see that by the difference in
  the color)
- Is this the correct way to apply one class or the other in
  Knockout? Or do I have to write `$index % 2 === 0` two times (one for each class)?

Which solutions are applicable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax is slightly wrong. You have to use `$index() % 2 === 0` and you are using the [css binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/css-binding.html) incorrect. This will work:

```
<div data-bind="css: { grid_row: $index() % 2 === 0, grid_a_row: $index() %2 === 1 }">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PYsc2/

Comment: this solution is simple and close to my original intent. Thanks for your clarifications!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are correct:

> Is this the correct way to apply one class or the other in
>   Knockout? Or do I have to write $index % 2 === 0 two times (one for each class)?

Your CSS binding syntax is incorrect, it should be:

```
css: { 'name-of-css-rule': function(){}, 'another-css-rule': function(){} }
```

In your case, you can make an observable like:

```
viewModel.myBooleanFunction = ko.computed(function() {
    return this.foo() % 0 === 0 ? "even" : "odd";
}, viewModel);
```

and in your CSS binding declare it like this:

```
data-bind="css: myBooleanFunction"
```

Those are dynamic CSS rules:
From: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/css-binding.html

Comment: Thanks! Very usefull! Do you also happen to know how can I pass the index of the iteration to the function?

Comment: Solved using a simple function instead of a computed and passing $index() to it.

Answer (score 1):

Or if you prefer to use [**attr** binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/attr-binding.html), you could use the coalesce operator like this.

```
data-bind="attr: { class: ($index() % 2 == 0) ? 'grid_row' : 'grid_a_row' }"
```

Please note that it will overwrite the class attribute completely and any other previously declared class will be lost.

Comment: +1 I was thinking about this too as an alternate solution. When using it, you have to be careful you don't have any additional classes on the element because I believe the attribute binding would overwrite them (which is why I'd rather use the css binding in order to prevent mistakes). Other than that works well.

Comment: @dhsto: i will keep that in mind. still a novice in knockoutjs. more and more amazed as each day passes. i tested. you are correct. it overwrites the attribute